# Writing to Excel based on row values

Tags: python, excel, list, row, xlwt

I have an Excel file that looks like this (Col4 values are not letters, but names):

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1    _        1      w
row2 | 3,2,7    _        2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     _        4      z
```

I want to write some values in column 2 that look like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1  x,y,w      1      w
row2 | 3,2,7   y,x       2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     z        4      z
```

I've gotten the col 2 values to print out, but my code currently prints all of it at once, and I'd like it to only print out the specific col2 values that belong to the same row as the corresponding col1 values (separated by commas).

My **code** to do this is:

```
def question():
    newtprint = list()
    solstice = list()
    for x in xrange(sheet.nrows):
        buddy = sheet.cell_value(x, 13) #"col1"
        newton = buddy.split(',')
        hont = newton, x #This defines the cell values and the row they belong to, I think this could be important to use to define col2 row values? Not sure how to use this in an if or for loop though
        james = sheet.col_values(15) #"col3"
        path = sheet.col_values(16) #"col4"
        for i in xrange(len(newton)): #for any values in col1
            for n in xrange(len(james)) or xrange(len(path)): #for any values in col3 or col4
                if james[n] == newton[i]: #if col3[value] == col1[value]
                    newtprint.append(path[n]) #append col4[value] into a list
        for name in newtprint: #takes list out of nested loops to print once
            print name
            sheety.write("col2 rows", 14, name) #writes values into col2
            wb.save('C:/.../names.xls')
```

I currently have no code to separate the values by a comma. But I know the `(',').join` function is used to accomplish this and I should be able to figure that out.

How to print the right values to the right row?

Comment: `','.join(list_of_text_elements)`

Comment: probably you have to move `newtprint = list()` inside `for x in xrange(sheet.nrows):` or you have to use `for` loops in different order.

Comment: So newtprint actually works correctly, as far as I've seen. The problem is not in the reading, but in the actual writing. 

I'm trying to get     **sheety.write**     to write "xyw" to col 2, row 1, and only that cell, instead of writing: cell 1 = x, cell 2 = y, cell 3 = w...

Comment: `sheety.write( ...,  ','.join(newtprint) )` ?

Comment: So, I have names like Jimmy, Burt, Macklin, John, etc. What this did is just split the names into character strings.

So I get J, I, M, M, Y, B, U, R, T, M, A.... etc. 

But again, I'm not too worried about the ','.join  function right now, I'm just trying to figure out how to deal with getting those names in the appropriate rows. Thanks though for helping me by the way.